# When is crosspaths set to true?

Tags: sbt, scala-2.11

I failed to find a good documentation about the use and purpose of **crosspaths**. Can someone point me to the documentation or answer these specific questions.

1. My Scala version is 2.11.6, but when **crosspaths** is set to true,
   I see two source folders - '`scala`' and '`scala-2.11`'. Shouldn't there
   be just one of these two? What is the meaning of these two folders?
2. What code goes in '`scala`' and what goes in '`scala-2.11`'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`crossPaths` is set to true to enable/disable [Cross-Building](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Cross-Build.html) (and it's true by default).

As of `sbt` 0.13.8 you're seeing that by default `sbt` handles source directories per Scala version, to remove the repetition of every project doing this themselves.

So if you have multiple Scala versions you're cross building against, out the box you have source directories where you can put that version-specific code.

But I agree that it's confusing: if you don't have multiple `crossScalaVersions` there's no need for both a `scala` and a `scala-2.11`.

The majority of your code should always live in `scala`, and if you ever have more than one Scala version you're cross building against *and* you have version-specific code then use `scala-2.11`, `scala-2.10`, etc.